# How can I migrate drive files into SPO using SPO Migration manager, but exclude sub-folders?

Tags: migration

I do a lot of migrations, but have come across a particularly messy drive I need to migrate into SPO. Normally, we just put the path of the folder into the CSV, site URL and DL (+Folder). This covers off most needs. *(MS SharePoint Migration Agent)*

The problem is if I need to migrate from a level 2 folder and map the level 3 folders to different locations. In the example below, the Red **Building** folder contains around 30 files that need to be migrated. The sub-folders are also migrated, but not all to the 'New Building Projects' DL. At the moment, the migration agent will put a copy of the Plans, Budget, Launch & Procurement folders, along with the 30 files into the New Building Projects DL. It will ALSO put a copy of Budget into Finance, Launch into Marketing etc. If I remove '..\Share\Projects\Building', it will prevent the duplicate folder imports, but it will also then not migrate the 30 files in the immediate folder.

Sorry for the complexity, but if you have had this scenario, I'd be keen to hear how you managed it, at scale.

Thank you
Scott

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-bulk-upload-format-csv-json there's no specification for excluding subfolders. I'm afraid you have to use the manual & traditional way of doing this, by moving the unwanted folders to other places that's not in the migration plan.

Even the paid migration tools out there (to my knowledge) there's no way to exclude specific subfolder(s). When you pick a folder, it'll pick everything beneath.